# Indoor Positioning System for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, indoor-positioning-system, redpin

I am looking at options for implementing Indoor Positioning System in a Windows Phone 7 app. This app is going to be used to guide users inside shopping malls, so location accuracy up to a few meters is very important. I googled a bit and came across Redpin - http://redpin.org which looks good but they don't have a ready client for Windows Phone 7 yet. Redpin only supports iOS and Android as of now.

Can anyone here help with this? Has anybody here implemented Indoor Positioning System on Windows Phone 7 app?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @Raj, the clients provided by RedPin are example projects which show how you can make user of a (local) RedPin server. If you have any knowledge of either Java or iOs and you want to try RedPin as a solution, I would download their sourceforge project [http://sourceforge.net/projects/redpin/files/release-3.1/] and give it a go.

Comment: @KooKiz - I am looking for any help / suggestions for the best options available to implement Indoor Positioning System on Windows Phone 7 at the moment. Which include any Redpin like SDKs which can work on Windows Phone 7. I hope that helps you with understanding my question

Comment: @ajmccall - Thanks mate. Redpin works well on iOS and Android. Unfortunately, there is no ready client library for Windows Phone 7 at the moment.

Comment: @Raj, I think (and I may well be wrong) but you're missing the point of RedPin. It looks like the open-source aspect is the server source they provide and the RESTful API [http://redpin.org/resources/docu/interface_spec.pdf] that goes with it. If you create a local server, you can upload maps to it, query for maps, upload locations to a map and query for locations based on Wifi signal patterns. There is no client library. If you can write and parse JSON web requests in WP7 then you can use RedPin as a solution (if applicable).

Comment: @ajmccall - Makes sense. I will dig into their server and give it a shot. Will update my findings in few days. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 does not provide enough information to be able to produce such a system without a very specific WiFi infrastructure.

To implement such a solution you would need to be able to access information about connected (or available) WiFi networks or access points and the signal strength of each. From these you could triangulate an approximate location.

However,
As the WP7 SDK does not provide information on an access point name or signal strength this becomes very difficult.

The only ways round this would be to identify a location by network name, assuming that each access point used a different name, so as to provide greater accuracy.
Or you had a proxy on the access points that could add additional location information to the request, so as to provide a greater level of accuracy without needing to create lots of uniquely named networks.
Either way would be a hack and be unlikely to produce the level of accuracy needed for your requirements. Unless you know you have the number of users with appropriate devices to justify creating such a system on WP7 at the moment I'd advise against this for now and hope that additional, required, functionality becomes available in a future version of the platform.

Comment: Helps, thanks. I wonder how exactly is Bing Indoor Maps doing it and how accurate it is? Room level accuracy is important and going by your answer, it does not look like it's going to be easy.

Comment: If the the SDK doesn't provide for signal strength then I would agree with @MattLacey. It's not going to be possible/trivial to do it based on WiFi, RedPin or other another system.

Comment: @RajChaudhari Bing Indoor Maps doesn't include internal positioning within a "few meters" as required in the question.

Comment: Did WP8 improved in this area? Does it provide name of access point and signal strength?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of indoor positioning API providers. Most options are for Android, but this would be a good place to start to see if anything has recently become available for WP7: https://bitly.com/indoornavigation

Comment: Thanks for the list. Unfortunately, there is'nt much for WP7 yet. The problem is even if the API's from these providers are HTTP based, there seems to be no way to send them the required wifi info from a WP7 device due to the limitations of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Many of these systems use a "finger printing" technology... meaning what happens is a person needs to make a recording of the indoor space radio environment.  That recording is then overlayed on the map to get the spaces unique radio fingerprint.  In theory it would work great (and it does) the problem is however the signals change.  The more users on any of the signal streams and the load will change the signal level or integrity.

If the signal changes more then 20% (in most cases) the recording needs to be redone.  Depending on the size of the space that may be a very time intensive process.

The other problem is about 6 months ago apple took the ability away to read the rssi values seen on the phone... with out that reading the finger printing tech will not work on an apple device.  That's why most of these API's are all android only... RedPin I don't think has updated their site to reflect that..

Answer (score -4):

you can simply use RFID like [NFC](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_Field_Communication) on windows phone:

http://rfidroundup.blogspot.com/2011/04/microsoft-to-bring-nfc-to-windows-phone.html
[image: NFC]

Or

if you can't wait for this OS version, you can use an Sound-Frequency indicator using build in Microphone. Peep sender and fourier analysis of noise detection.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

[image: Microphone WP7]

For more concept details, you need to share some details with me.

Comment: A non-existent API mentioned in a year-old article, about a technology that isn't in Windows Phone yet? And using the 'sound' from stores in shopping malls? As if this entire idea couldn't get difficult enough...

Comment: You linked a short article, and the sample page for all the WP7 code samples -- on which, the word 'frequency' is never used, and 'sound' is used in 3 places: 1 for playing music, and twice for games. I DID read your post in completion. It wasn't relevant, hence the downvote.

Comment: thats the reason I've posted the image. I sit there and remind me how to solve that problem and got a solution. Others just say "not possible". RFID is the most common way to do that. If not build in, you can use a RFID adapter. I don't understand your downvote.

Comment: RFID wouldn't be appropriate for this scenario (even if it was available on the device or via a connected device-if that was also possible). To work over the kind of distances necessary for this to be practical in a shopping mall would mean you would need antenas on the device larger than the device to work at the frequencies necessary. The there would be the cost of the infrastructure in the mall and the massive battery drain that powering such long range readers on the phone would require.